# Domain driven design and ORM limitations

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

Most of the DDD examples I see are written in Java and vast majority use Hibernate for persisting and fetching entities. I really don't have any experience with both and I'm assuming Hibernate is a tool good enough to resolve dependencies, deal with value objects and so on. My ORM of choice is Doctrine2 and as far as I know this is the best tool PHP currently has, but it isn't enough in my opinion to support DDD principles.

Here's an example of domain layer:

```php
/**
 * Simple value object
 */
class ProductId
{
    private $value;

    function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function value()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

/**
 * Example dependency
 */
class Dependency
{
    public function doNothing()
    {

    }
}

/**
 * Game class done in a DDD manner
 */
class Game
{
    /**
     * @var ProductId
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var Dependency
     */
    private $dependency;

    function __construct(ProductId $id, $title, Dependency $dependency)
    {
        $this->id    = $id;
        $this->title = $title;

        // Validation
        Assertion::minLength(25, $title);
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductId
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function someBehavior()
    {
        $this->dependency->doNothing();
    }
}
```

Now with Doctrine you could use XML or YAML mappings to map `Game` to some table.
However upon calling `$gameRepository->productOfId($someId);` what you would get is a malformed object. Here's why:

1. Since Doctrine2 doesn't support value objects when calling `getId()` you would get a plain `int`, since its mapping will be pointing to an integer column. Newest beta kinda supports them but still it isn't very flexible, nor easy to configure in more complex scenarios.
2. Since Doctrine2 create proxy objects for retrieval upon calling `someBehavior()` on a fetched entity you'd get a fatal error because proxy objects don't resolve constructor dependencies. This can be actually overcome by creating some `DomainRegistry` singleton and getting dependencies from there but I REALLY don't like that's implied on me. However we're still skipping validation because of constructor not being called and I wouldn't rely on database integrity only.

How should I overcome that? I'd rather not use some `if is int return ProductId(int)` things inside my domain model since I want my domain layer to be persistence-ignorant.

One thing that came to my mind is (assuming that i'll stick to ORM, not just DBAL) to treat Doctrine entities like DTOs (I hope I use that term correctly here) and assemble domain objects from them. So besides mentioned classes I'd have something like that:

```php
/**
 * Doctrine entity treated like a pure value container
 */
class GameDTO
{
    private $id;
    private $title;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}

class DoctrineGameRepository
{
    /**
     * @var Dependency
     */
    private $dependency;

    /**
     * Doctrine's entity manager
     */
    private $em;

    function __construct(Dependency $dependency, $em)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function productOfId($id)
    {        
        /** @var GameDTO $gameDto */
        $gameDto = $this->em->find($id);

        return new Game($gameDto->getId(), $gameDto->getTitle(), $this->dependency);        
    }
}
```

That way I am overcoming an infrastructure limitations, but it adds another layer of complexity. Also how should I handle changes to the object that need to be also reflected to my DTO so I can update my database?

My second thought was to adapt CQRS, but that's just a buzzword for me since I haven't researched it too much yet. I know it principles but I don't know which classes and repositories should I model for that.

How would you handle all of this?

Comment: DDD does not depend on Hibernate.  It's not even necessary to use Hibernate in Java projects.

Comment: @duffymo, I never said so. I used it as a theoretical opposing example to way Doctrine does things. Like I said - I don't really know if Hibernate solves everything, but that's out of the questions scope.

Comment: Personally I'm always ranting to people about how it's best to cut your ORM off at the repositories.  There's too many reasons to list, but think always of "Do I want my domain model polluted with data-centric artifacts and properties?".  I'd strongly recommend from a DDD point of view, treating your ORM entities as DTOs, using them to populate domain entities and return these from your repositories.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips, but how do you deal with updating your database data? Since DTOs and not DDD entities are under ORM, every change I do in my domain model needs to be somehow reflected to DTO.

Comment: @acid in my case (.NET development) I come across Entity Framework ORM the most, which I use in it's 'Database First' paradigm.  So I simply make the domain model changes, then the database changes and get Entity Framework to regenerate the DTOs automatically.  When I come across NHibernate or EF using the 'Code First' paradigm, then I have to maintain changes to the DTOs too.  Alternatively, in my own projects, I used RavenDB (a document database) where I can persist domain entities without any ORM, DTOs or mappings.

Comment: @acid have you come to any pleasing conclusions since posting this? I am stuck with Doctrine myself, hating every minute of it, but haven't really found an alternative (for PHP) that I can really get behind. The ORM seems to influence every design decision and works against every good principle I've learned from DDD. It's very frustrating, and I would rather not resort to Doctrine as an overly complex, bloated, slow DTO layer - if I'm going to painstakingly hand-write mappings from DTOs to real entities anyhow, I'd prefer something simple and lightweight at the DTO level... any clues?

Answer (score 3):

I think the question raises a good point.

**Should limitations of the ORM affect your DDD design ?**

I code in java most of the time and I am aware of how hibernate has evolved, 3-4 years back even hibernate did not support value objects,the support for embedded objects was also quite naive and it looks like Doctrine2 is at that stage

I think the magic of ORM is less required once you lean towards CQRS, I think that CQRS and DDD go hand in hand, CQRS is pretty [simple](http://codeofrob.com/entries/cqrs-is-too-complicated.html) if implemented on its own, its only when ES is added into the equation that it gets complicated (ES has its benefits).

So i would advocate that you go with basic CQRS for all projects you want to use DDD concepts on. So from here we can assume that you have a Finder/Query class to look after your queries, these should probably be straight SQL's

Not lets get down to the meaty bit the repository. Once we have the queries out the repository, the repository is actually simple, the interface it exposes will be real tight here is an example.

```
public interface Repository<T> {

    T load(Object aggregateIdentifier);    
    void add(T aggregate);
    void update (T aggregate);
}
```

You can have an implementation for each aggregate you have in the system.

Here you can take care of marshalling your aggregate out of your result set the way you seem fit. This might be some effort, but the cost can be amortized across projects and you are free from all the ORM black magic :)

Comment: I really like your reassurance on CQRS, but I still need to deal with ORM's black magic since write model will be under ORM. Example - `Product` has two `Price<amount,currency>` objects - `regular` and `final`. They represent total 4 columns in db (`reg_amount, reg_currency, fin_amount, fin_currency`). Doctrine requires me to create four primitive columns in order to save that. Where should the transformation occur? I really don't want to pollute my write model with additional properties extorted on me by my ORM.

Comment: I am encouraging you to consider dumping the ORM and writing your own insert/update queries, this way you can manage the mappings between your domain model and the relational model.

Comment: But do you suggest I do full row update even if I change one column `void update (T aggregate);`? Or should I somehow check what to run update against? Can you provide some example of implementation?

Comment: I would do a full update. We use the Axon framework, I will try and did through its source code to find the relevant implementation.

Comment: What does *ES* stand for?

Comment: @rgvcorley I guess it's Event Sourcing